# How to style input tag without class with JSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I am using the react-select component on my app. I am also only styling my app with JSS. My issue is that since react-select is an npm package, I don't have the capability to modify class names in the component. So there is an input in there that I need to target with my styles.

```
<div class="Select-input"><input type="text" name="style-me" /></div>
```

And my JSS is a little something like this:

```
jss.setup(preset());

const stylus = {
   'Select-input': {
       background: 'red'
   }
}

const { classes } = jss.createStyleSheet(stylus).attach();
```

What do I need to do in JSS to style that child input tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41134360/2518200) answer, you *can* pass in a class name for react-select. The rest of my answer shows how to target child elements.

---

I checked the github page for JSS here:
https://github.com/cssinjs/jss

They have a live example for nested CSS rules here:
https://github.com/cssinjs/examples/blob/gh-pages/plugins/jss-nested/simple/app.js

In the code to target a nested `<button>` element, it uses a property named `& button`. Notice the space between the ampersand and `button`. So for your specific code, you can target the `<input>` like this:

```
jss.setup(preset());

const stylus = {
   'Select-input': {
       background: 'red',
       '& input': {
            /* your input styles here */
       }
   }
}

const { classes } = jss.createStyleSheet(stylus).attach();
```

Comment: Awesome answer, couldn't have been better. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're referring to this package:

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select

You can in fact pass in `className` as a prop

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the comment, i didn't know you could target the input as well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have always at least 2 ways:

1. Pass the generated class name

Use JSS as you should by default, avoid unscoped class names. Use generated class name and pass it to the component you want to use

```
const {classes} = jss.createStyleSheet({
  input: {background: 'red'}
}).attach()


<Input className={classes.input} />
```

2. Use scoped global selector

If its impossible to pass a class name, you can still have a locally scoped global selector

```
const {classes} = jss.createStyleSheet({
  container: {
    '@global': {
      input: {background: 'red'}
    }
  }
}).attach()

<div className={classes.container}>
  <Input />
</div>
```